# How to loop the string to get unique name

Tags: c#

```
[{
        "Checklist_0": "1"
    }, {
        "Checklist_1": "0"
    }, {
        "Checklist_2": "1"
    }, {
        "Checklist_3": "0"
    }, {
        "Checklist_4": "0"
    }, {
        "Checklist_5": "1"
    }, {
        "Checklist_6": "0"
    }
]
```

This is what my out I need to replace all the `Checklist_i` values with one value

Any suggestions?

Comment: for (var i=0;i<=20; i++)
                {
                    StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
                    SB.Append(H);
                    //string k1 = H.Replace("Checklist_" + i + "", "Pinki");
                    SB.Replace("Checklist_" + i + "", "Pinki");
                    //SB.Append(k1);
                    //string K = Request.CheckListStatus.Replace("Checklist_0", "Pinki");
                }

Comment: edit your post and place the code in the post

Comment: That string looks like JSON. Please see this post: [How to parse JSON with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Comment: I tried but no luck

Comment: Can any one please help

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expressions is one way

```
string result = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("Checklist_[\\d]").Replace(input, "foo");
```